# The behaviour of a prime over quadratic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $d$ be a positive integer such that $-d$ is a fundamental discriminant, and let $p$ be a rational prime. It is well-known how to detect whether $p$ splits in the quadratic field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$, namely by the indicator function

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \left(1 + \left(\frac{-d}{p} \right) \right).$$

For such a split prime $p$, is there a reasonable way to determine whether or not the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ above $p$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ has order at most two in the class group?

If the order is anything other than $2$ then this question is likely as hard as computing the class group given $d$, which is very difficult indeed. However Gauss's genus theory provides with significant control over the 2-torsion part of the class groups of quadratic fields, so perhaps this case can be handled reasonably well.

Comment: Determining whether this ideal is *principal* is a well known problem of representing $p$ as $x^2+dy^2$. As you probably know, Cox has an entire book dedicated solely to that question, and the answer is related to splitting in the Hilbert class field $H$ of $K$. For order at most two, I suspect there may be similar characterizations in terms of the subfield of $H$ fixed by the $2$-torsion subgroup of the class group.

Comment: Splitting is determined by $(-d/p)$; of course it is also determined by $f((-d/p))$ for any injective function, but there's no reason at all to invoke such an $f$. If you know the prime factors $q$ of $d$ you can test whether the class of the primes above $p$ have order $2$ by checking whether any of the numbers $pq$ is principal. In addition, there are several fast ways for computing the $2$-class group (see e.g. Bosma and Stevenhagen).